# Proof of a vector identity for adjoint heat transfer

Tags: tensor-products

I have a domain $\Omega$ and the expression below. S, T and $\alpha$ are scalar fields.
$$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}T\nabla\cdot(\kappa(\alpha)\nabla S)\;d\Omega$$
I have read in a publication that this equals:
$$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial \kappa(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}\nabla T \cdot\nabla S \;d\Omega$$
I am not able to prove this.

My first attempt was splitting the first expression:
$$\int_\Omega \frac{\partial \kappa(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha}T\Delta S+T\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\nabla \kappa(\alpha) \cdot \nabla S \;d\Omega$$
Though I don't know if this helps.